# Optimize metadata writing in DOC, XLS files

Tags: java, apache-poi, apache-tika

I'm doing a program that modifies only the metadata (standard and custom) in files Doc, xls, ppt and Vsd, the program works correctly but I wonder if there is a way to do this without loading the entire file into memory:

POIFSFileSystem POIFS = new POIFSFileSystem (new FileInputStream ("file.xls"))

The NPOIFSFileSystem method is faster and consumes less memory but is read only.

I'm using Apache POI 3.9

Comment: NPOIFS is nearly ready for write support, might contributing some fixes to it be possible?

Comment: Of course, how I can help?

Comment: If you [send an email to the dev@ list](http://poi.apache.org/mailinglists.html) I'll give you advice there, it's more than can fit in a comment block! Basically there are a couple of disabled failing unit tests that need their underlying logic fixing, and a couple of stub unit tests that need writing

Answer (score 0):

You could map the desired part to memory and then work on it using [`java.nio.FileChannel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html).

> In addition to the familiar read, write, and close operations of byte channels, this class defines the following file-specific operations:
>
> > > - Bytes may be read or written at an absolute position in a file in a way that does not affect the channel's current position.
> > > - A region of a file may be mapped directly into memory; for large files this is often much more efficient than invoking the usual read or write methods.

Comment: That wouldn't be much fun on a binary file which can store chunks of data in different bits within there...

Comment: I'm not sure if I fully get you. If he needs to work with bits/bytes he just needs to define masks for every type of file that provide methods for getting/setting the desired meta data values.

Comment: If only it were that simple to work with the OLE2 based file formats like that! It's basically a mini filesystem, and the properties get stored in a structured stream within that, and each 512 bytes can be stored anywhere in the file in any order...

Comment: Hmm, I don't what OLE2 is. But my first thought would be to provide some kind of abstraction for that particular problem, so other components could use a clean interface without bothering about where to find the following bytes.

Comment: ...but it can't be used together with fileChannel. And there is no similar mechanism? :/ ...I have nothing left then, except for extending the library with this feature.

Comment: NPOIFSFileSystem supports NIO, but not (yet) writing. POIFSFileSytem predates NIO so doesn't. That bit was covered in the question...!

Answer (score 0):

At the time of your question, there sadly wasn't a very low memory way to do it. The good news is that as of 2014-04-28 it is possible! (This code should be in 3.11 when that's released, but for now it's too new)

Now that NPOIFS supports writing, including in-place write, what you'll want to do is something like:

```
// Open the file, and grab the entries for the summary streams
NPOIFSFileSystem poifs = new NPOIFSFileSystem(file, false);
DocumentNode sinfDoc = 
     (DocumentNode)root.getEntry(SummaryInformation.DEFAULT_STREAM_NAME);
DocumentNode dinfDoc = 
     (DocumentNode)root.getEntry(DocumentSummaryInformation.DEFAULT_STREAM_NAME);

// Open and parse the metadata
SummaryInformation sinf = (SummaryInformation)PropertySetFactory.create(
     new NDocumentInputStream(sinfDoc));
DocumentSummaryInformation dinf = (DocumentSummaryInformation)PropertySetFactory.create(
     new NDocumentInputStream(dinfDoc));

// Make some metadata changes
sinf.setAuthor("Changed Author");
sinf.setTitle("Le titre \u00e9tait chang\u00e9");
dinf.setManager("Changed Manager");

// Update the metadata streams in the file
sinf.write(new NDocumentOutputStream(sinfDoc));
dinf.write(new NDocumentOutputStream(dinfDoc));

// Write out our changes
fs.writeFilesystem();
fs.close();
```

You ought to be able to do all of that in under 20% of the memory of the size of your file, quite possibly less than that for larger files!

(If you want to see more on this, look at the [ModifyDocumentSummaryInformation example](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/src/examples/src/org/apache/poi/hpsf/examples/ModifyDocumentSummaryInformation.java) and the [HPSF TestWrite unit test](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/src/testcases/org/apache/poi/hpsf/basic/TestWrite.java))